# type 'Response<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to decode JSON Data using JsonDecode().  when I try to access each member through [] indexing and try to print them, the above error is printed onto my terminal. I am trying to build an expense tracker app that uses a pie chart to display the different expenses of the user.

Here is a small snippet of the code. I can provide more if needed.

var expense = Expense(
_dateController.text, categories.toString(), money);

```
                token.storage.read(key: "jwt").then((value)  {
                  AuthService().getExpense(value).then((val) => {
                    
                     print(val),  // this prints the json data  
                     mv = jsonDecode(val), // i tried to decode it 
                     item = mv[0], //acessing each member
                     print(item['category']),  


                     

                  });
                });
```

Once again the error I get is:
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Response' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: Can you please show the json?

Answer (score 0):

it is giviing error because return type of api call is of type **Response** and print function can print string only try to conver that value into string using .**toString** method. also if you are making an api call you should accces its **body** to print.

for example :

```
token.storage.read(key: "jwt").then((value)  {
              AuthService().getExpense(value).then((val) => {
                
                 print(val.body.toString),  // change here
          
              });
            });
```